# Create a shortcut for broken key in keyboard?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

My friend's <kbd>u</kbd> key is not working in it's keyboard. Is it possible to create a shortcut for <kbd>u</kbd> and <kbd>U</kbd> in Ubuntu?